# How i can get a value in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that looks like this:

[image: my database]

And my code like this:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot uniqueKey:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot keysiswa:uniqueKey.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot valuesiswa:keysiswa.child("nama_siswa").getChildren()) {
                    String c = valuesiswa.getValue().toString();
                    Log.i(TAG,c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to take the value of "nama_siswa" but nothing happens in logcat. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: are these users?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("siswa");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Name:",dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).name); // define your pojo class
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the respond,can explain it when i use for?

Comment: you already have a documentation,its very rude not to accept sb answer with the pretense to explain it

Comment: it read data from firebase database as siswa node inside child node.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of `nama_siswa` property, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference siswaRef = rootRef.child("siswa");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String nama_siswa = ds.child("nama_siswa").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", nama_siswa);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
siswaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
chandra
coba
```